# How to manage detailed description and links in google?

Tags: search, seo

A client would like to have his website implemented like the following one, on google: 
https://www.google.ch/search?q=mlzd&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a

With:

- a list of links to the differents sections of the website.
- the google function with the arrow (on rollover of the links) to get previews of the website pages.

So, here are my questions:

1. Do you know to implement the several links? Is it  tags?
2. Do I then have to do something to get the google images previews, or is it automatic?
3. Will the google images previews work, with a Flash website? If not, the preview will be a screenshot the website with no flash enabled?

Thank you a lot for your answers!!
David

Comment: I know I have just answered, you but actully this type of question is a better fit for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ rather than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

1. The links are called Sitelinks, they are automatic. You cant do anything to sepefically enable them. 
   http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334
2. The preview is automatic, but you do need to make sure that 1) allow google to cache the url (ie avoid "nocache" and 2) not block in anyway the Previews https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-instant-previews
3. See link in the previous answer